# Android Ripple effect not appears when click on recyclerview items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Ripple effects on the RecyclerView just appears when click on space area. (Photo 1)

[image]

When the image or textview is clicked, the effect does not appear! 
what is the problem? (Photo 2)

[image]

Here is my code:
recylcer_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_listrow_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_listrow_text"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#010101"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/recycler_listrow_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting both `foreground` and `background`. And make it `clickable=true`

Like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_listrow_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_listrow_text"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#010101"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/recycler_listrow_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```